# Redundant navigation icons in iOS ap

Tags: navigation, ios

One of our clients want to have on the home screen of their (iOS) app the same buttons that are on the bottom tab bar, we see that as redundant and not user friendly at all, is it acceptable to do so?

Oh, and does it violate any of apple app design guidelines?

Comment: Hi @James.  Welcome to the site!  Asking for "any ideas?" isn't a very specific question.  Can you edit your post to make it more precise what you're asking?  Explaining a bit more about what the app does and who its target audience is would help as well.

Comment: Is it a home screen that users go back to, or is it a splash screen. If they can go back to it, what ways are there of going back to it? Does it feature as one of the views of the tab bar?

Comment: It's a home screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well designed applications provide the user a path and design a journey where he begins and completes his/her task following few steps. If you are designing a journey, you may not want to provide two doors (which are side by side) when both lead to the same passage. Considering that, I wouldn't favor the idea of keeping two controls which perform the same function and both are available right on the same screen at the same level.

Benny has mentioned multiple assess points which is a nice feature but my interpretation of multiple entry points is that they should exist at different levels so that users with different navigational preferences be able to begin their journey. In that sense, placing something on the screen is one level and a second level could be placing the same command in a context menu. But in your case, if you put two icons at two locations on the same screen, you are still using the same level and this doesn't qualify to be a "multiple-entry-point" approach. Also for Mobile Apps, I wouldn't be too keen to use multiple entry points as real-estate is scarce resource and you wan to use it as economically as possible.

Concluding: I wouldn't want to put a bottom navigation on the Home-screen.

Comment: Thanks, we have actually come to an agreement to use grid style navigation on the home screen, and tab based navigation in the app.

Answer (score 2):

Having different ways to access the same content is fundamental in UX. Some users love to search, others navigate. In your case your customer acknowledge the different users who want to navigate on top screen bar (hiding content while doing so) and navigate on bottom bar.

Which way is correct? I don't know, but your users know. And the answer would most certainly be either top or bottom. I'd implement this as a cool feater where the user could swipe the entire navigation bar to be either in the top or at the bottom.

A quick guide on your next update could explain to your users what they can do and you support both kind of users, your customer and your next invoice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we think that we can use both in the same app by having a home screen that displays the main options in a grid or icons, and when in the main app (not the home screen) the tab bar will be used for navigation